# Does Chat REST API have any methods controlling where new chats open?

Tags: liveagent, configuration, chat

My agents have come to me and asked if it is possible to control the placement of newly opened chats in Live Agent.  The way it's set up now is that when an available agent accepts a new chat - the tab for that particular chat automatically opens.

This means that if the agent is already working on other chats when the new one pops up and is in the middle of writing something there - he/she has to use the mouse to click between all the tabs and find again the one he/she was in the middle of working on.

I'm not finding anything about this in the docs, and if it is there, I haven't found it.  If so it'd be great to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Seems that chat option setting is to assigned as  automatically accept chat,  If you stop, user will have to click on accept button until then it will not get opened in new tab

Comment: Actually, no.  we do not have that set as part of the presence configuration.  Strange.